# Detect text selection changes in UIWebView text selection

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

There are lots of guides on how to get the selected text in `UIWebView` but I can't seem to find any on how to detect the change in selection. I understand that I could simply detect taps elsewhere and always get the latest selection, but I'd like to create a standalone view that wraps all this functionality.

I currently have a view that holds the `UIWebView` instance and handles the parsing and passing the content to the web view. As far as I know, detecting taps would require a custom window implementation (instructed [here](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/)). I'd like to follow separation of concerns and avoid any custom window implementations if possible.

Any ideas how could I achieve this within a view? I already tried javascript but I guess I was 
not that competent with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.addEventListener("selectionchange")` which fires whenever the selection changes, and forward those changes to Obj-C through a bridge.

Bridges:

1. [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge)
2. [JavaScriptCore](https://github.com/TomSwift/UIWebView-TS_JavaScriptContext)

Example Code:

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(){
    bridge.send("selectionchange"); // WebViewJavaScriptBridge
    bridge.selectionChanged();  // JavaScriptCore
}, false);
```

Comment: Mind sharing an example?

Comment: @RobCaraway I've been messing around with UIWebView, there's actually a few ways. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: how to get `document` variable?

Comment: @NikeAlive The example code I posted if Javascript. The `document` variable is a global variable that is automatically available when you are writing (web) javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally mistaken, there's no way to detect if the selection range changes when using `UIWebView` and javascript combination. My solution was to poll the selection range instead of notifying of its changes. Currently I have no need for real-time updates, so it will be sufficient only to know if there's a selection or not. The text selection is retrieved on demand and for the selection change, I use the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

For the clearing of the selection I had to use a small delay. The selection is not cleared instantly after the tap.

```
- (void)tap:(id)sender
{    
    [self updateSelection];
    // A simple hack to detect when selection is cleared.
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateSelection) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5];
}
```